# loadData in Webview raises WebPageNotAvailableException

Tags: android, android-webview

When I try to set data in webview with *loadData*, I get WebPageNotAvailableException.

Here is my code:

```
String displaytext =' "Some big html text"';

WebView wvDis = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webviewDisplay);
wvDis.loadData(displaytext, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Here is the text itself:

```
<p>Als Ergänzung zum bestehenden Team suchen wir für unseren Partner einen zuverlässigen, teamfähigen Bauabdichter/ Flachdachisoleur.</p><p>Gerne würden wir Ihnen näheres von dieser interessanten Stelle in einem Gespräch berichten, wenn Sie:</p><p> </p><ul><li>über einen eidg. Berufsabschluss als Spengler, Polybauer, Bauabdichter oder Flachdachisoleur verfügen oder über jahrelange Berufserfahrung verfügen und dies mit entsprechenden Arbeitszeugnissen belegen können.</li><li> 100% dichte Schweissnähte hinterlassen und über die nötigen Zertifikate verfügen Bsp. Sarnafil, Sarnafil T usw.</li><li>sich gewohnt sind selbstständig zu arbeiten</li><li>die deutsche Sprache mündlich und schriftlich verstehen</li><li>den Führerschein Kat. B besitzen</li><li>an einer langfristigen Anstellung interessiert sind</li><li>körperlich robust gebaut sind</li></ul><p>Im Gegenzug wird Ihnen in dieser Anstellung geboten:</p><ul><li>faire Entlöhnung</li><li>aufgestelltes kollegiales Team</li><li>Einsatzbetrieb mit gutem Ruf</li><li>langfristige Anstellung</li><li>selbstständiges Arbeiten</li><li>nach Eignung können auch Servicearbeiten dazukommen</li></ul><p>Sie fühlen sich angesprochen? Zögern Sie nicht und kontaktieren Sie uns.</p><p> </p>
```

Comment: here html tag convert into html so that not display in String, but actually i use llike String str = "<p>something</P>" like that

Comment: you should ask in some manner. you should have knowledge of how to ask question.

Comment: I'm confused. Why is this question in German? Your title and comments are in English. You're not bound to get many answers in its current form. It's very difficult (even with the English title and summary) to  tell what you're asking.

Comment: I've edited your question, made it readable and you moved it back to unreadable. Good effort. At least read the answer... @Rob Hruska : the german part is his HTML :/

Comment: @Hitesh Dhamshaniya : look at my answer, if you have still problem after geting answer from Kheldar. Thanx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok not to worry, Try this..

```
   WebView web;

         String html="<html> <body> <p>Als Ergänzung zum bestehenden Team suchen
          wir für unseren Partner einen zuverlässigen, teamfähigen Bauabdichter/
        Flachdachisoleur.</p><p>Gerne würden wir Ihnen näheres von dieser interessanten
      Stelle in einem Gespräch berichten, wenn Sie:</p><p> </p><ul><li>über einen eidg.
     Berufsabschluss als Spengler, Polybauer, Bauabdichter oder 
     Flachdachisoleur verfügen
    oder über jahrelange Berufserfahrung verfügen und dies mit entsprechenden 
     Arbeitszeugnissen belegen können.</li><li> 100% dichte Schweissnähte hinterlassen
    und über die nötigen Zertifikate verfügen Bsp. Sarnafil, Sarnafil T usw.
    </li><li>sich
    gewohnt sind selbstständig zu arbeiten</li><li>die deutsche Sprache mündlich und
    schriftlich verstehen</li><li>den Führerschein Kat. B besitzen</li><li>an einer
   langfristigen Anstellung interessiert sind</li><li>körperlich robust gebaut sind</li>
     </ul><p>Im Gegenzug wird Ihnen in dieser Anstellung geboten:</p><ul><li>faire 
       Entlöhnung</li><li>aufgestelltes kollegiales Team</li><li>Einsatzbetrieb mit 
      gutem Ruf</li><li>langfristige Anstellung</li><li>selbstständiges Arbeiten</li>
       <li>nach Eignung können auch Servicearbeiten dazukommen</li></ul><p>Sie 
       fühlen sich 
       angesprochen? Zögern Sie nicht und kontaktieren Sie uns.</p><p> </p>  
       </body> </html>";


        web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);

        web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's loadDataWithBaseURL (instead of loadData) that gets rid of that '%' charachter that causes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

From reading the code, I'll point out to you that the official documentation states:

```
 String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

is the proper use for loadData. Your **HTML code fed to loadData** is not a valid HTML page, with

```
<html>
```

and

```
<body>
```

tags, it's only a paragraph mess...

Comment: can you try the string (after include html and body tag) which Hitesh given within webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");

Comment: who are goes with this answer please try it with this string and  webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
 and if its work then please explain it. Thanx.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean user370305. However, I'm on VS right now, not going to reboot Linux to test with Eclipse :p

Comment: I tried webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8"); for given string by hitesh and its not working that's why. Anyway. Thanx:-)